# Solvable subgroups of groups of polynomial automorphisms

Tags: gr.group-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Does every finitely generated free solvable group embed into the group of polynomial automorphisms of some C^n?

Comment: This is related to the Jacobian conjecture, and so I've retagged as algebraic-geometry and commutative-algebra.  I don't have an answer, but have you looked for stuff in van den Essen's book "Polynomial automorphisms and the Jacobian conjecture"? It seems like the first place to start looking.

Comment: sorry, what does "free solvable" mean?  The free group I know are not very solvable.

Comment: That's a good point.  I was just ignoring the word free as meaningless there.

Comment: "Free solvable" could mean e.g. a free k-step solvable group. Explicitly, this is F/D^k(F), where F is a free group and D^*(F) its derived series. I don't know the context well enough to know if this is what was meant.

Answer (score 1):

Wilhelm Magnus (W. Magnus, Über $n$-dimensionale Gittertransformationen. Acta Math. 64 (1935), no. 1, 353--367.) seems to have shown that the free metabelian group on $n$ generators has a faithful representation of degree $2$. It follows that there is a copy of the free solvable group on $n$ generators and of derived length $2$ inside $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$.

That answers your question affirmatively in a special case.